# Set multiple authorized keys for multiple users on same host in playbook

Tags: loops, ansible

I create users on a remote host:

```
 - name: Add Existing Users to Server
  user:
    name: "{{ item }}"
    groups: admin, prog
    generate_ssh_key: yes
    ssh_key_bits: 2048
    ssh_key_file: .ssh/id_rsa
  register: result
  with_items:
    - user1
    - user2
    - user3
    - user4
    - user5
    - user6
    - user7
- debug:
    msg: "{{ result.results | map(attribute='ssh_public_key') | list }}"
```

That creates all the users and their directories just fine. I can access the result array from the debug message, and it looks something like this:

```
ok: [192.168.blah.blah] => {
    "msg": [
        "ssh-rsa blahblahblahblahblahblah ansible-generated on TEST",
        "ssh-rsa blahblahblahblahblahblah ansible-generated on TEST",
        "same thing for rest of users....."
    ]
}
```

The problem is I don't know how to access this later in the next task. Here is the key generation task:

```
- name: Set authorized keys for users
  authorized_key:
    user: "{{ item }}"
    state: present
    key: #Need to access that generated list here, but how? 
  with_items:
    - user1
    - user2
    - user3
    - user4
    - user5
    - user6
    - user7
```

Is this possible to do with loops in ansible?

Comment: Why do you want to add users' own public key to authorized list on the same host?

Comment: Everyone has their own directory and key. I didn't make the system. I'm just doing what I'm supposed to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to access the result array, loop through it, and set the keys:

**Former code:**

```
- name: Set authorized keys for users
authorized_key:
  user: "{{ item }}"
  state: present
  key: #Need to access that generated list here, but how? 
with_items:
  - user1
  - user2
  - user3
  - user4
  - user5
  - user6
  - user7
```

**Working code**

```
- name: Set authorized keys for users
authorized_key:
  user: "{{ item.name }}" #Grabs the username from each object
  state: present
  key: "{{ item.ssh_public_key }}" #Grabs the ssh key from each object
loop: "{{ result.results | list }}" #Loops over the object array
```

This correctly generates the authorized_key file for each user.